# Only allow iframe to load content

Tags: iframe, x-frame-options

I have a service that is loaded through an iframe on exampledomain.org. Ideally, I only want this service to be loaded under exampledomain.org. This I can ensure with X-Frame Options. However I also don't want it be accessible by simply pasting the url into the browser. Is there a way to prevent anything except an iframe from loading content?

Answer (score 0):

This will make it only loosely enforced, but you can put a bit of JS on the framed page to take you back to the page you intended them to be on. One check you could try is to see if `window.parent` is the same as `window`.

```
if (window.parent === window) {
    location = "https://exampledomain.org/";
}
```