# How would I force my page to be loaded *only* in an iframe

Tags: security, web, iframe

I want to host a webpage that can only be served via iframes within my own domain.

An example of this in the wild would be Codepen. They sandbox the content of a "pen" in an iframe, but if you try to load the url from a browser it responds with an empty page.

I understand there might be multiple answers to this question but I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Would I be checking the referrer server side? Are there any other options?

Comment: one solution could be validating URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referer is a good start for the server side.

Also you can  try using CORS headers:
[Only allow iframe to load content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247407/only-allow-iframe-to-load-content)

Or validating using client side javascript code:
[How to identify if a webpage is being loaded inside an iframe or directly into the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t)

Also check info about `referrerpolicy`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-referrerpolicy

Comment: So, @Pure, was this your final solution?